# present and absent in one query using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have following mysql query:

```
SELECT m.emp_id     AS `Empid` 
     , d.dt        AS `AbsentDate`,
(CASE WHEN p.punch_status IS NULL
                           THEN 'A'
                           ELSE p.punch_status
                  END 

                  )  s
  FROM ( SELECT DATE(t.added_date) AS dt
           FROM pmc_attendance t
        WHERE date(t.added_date) >= '2018-08-01' 
            AND date(t.added_date) < DATE_ADD( '2018-08-31' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(t.added_date)
          ORDER BY DATE(t.added_date)
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN tbl_admin_users m
  LEFT
  JOIN  pmc_attendance p
    ON date(p.added_date) >= d.dt
   AND date(p.added_date) <  d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND p.emp_id = m.emp_id
 WHERE p.emp_id IS NULL  and m.emp_id='000838' group by d.dt
 ORDER
    BY m.emp_id
     , d.dt
```

this would fetch all the absent records of the employee but i want to show present dates of employees also.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niRsO.png)

my sql record shows:

```
Empid     AbsentDate   
000838    2018-08-05
000838    2018-08-05
000838    2018-08-11
000838    2018-08-12
000838    2018-08-15
000838    2018-08-19
```

I have use two tables 
1. tbl_admin_users-  employee data stored
2. pmc_attendance- present records of employees

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: How are you recording in the database that employees are present? You haven't shown us your source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in my query, I had removed `p.emp_id IS NULL` condition.
Due to this condition all your record which have `p.punch_status is not null` get filter out.

So you can try below query

```
SELECT m.emp_id     AS `Empid` 
     , d.dt        AS `AbsentDate`,
(CASE WHEN p.punch_status IS NULL
                           THEN 'A'
                           ELSE p.punch_status
                  END 

                  )  s
  FROM ( SELECT DATE(t.added_date) AS dt
           FROM pmc_attendance t
        WHERE date(t.added_date) >= '2018-08-01' 
            AND date(t.added_date) < DATE_ADD( '2018-08-31' ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY DATE(t.added_date)
          ORDER BY DATE(t.added_date)
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN tbl_admin_users m
  LEFT
  JOIN  pmc_attendance p
    ON date(p.added_date) >= d.dt
   AND date(p.added_date) <  d.dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND p.emp_id = m.emp_id
 WHERE m.emp_id='000838' group by d.dt
 ORDER
    BY m.emp_id
     , d.dt
```

Comment: please don't provide code dumps without an explanation. People will want to know _why_ they should change the code and also exactly what has changed. Code without context is not very useful. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand, why wait until then?

Comment: Oh I see, you meant "I _was_ waiting", not "I _am_ waiting". Since you used the present tense I thought you meant you are still waiting now. Just a small language misunderstanding. Thanks for updating the answer anyway.

Comment: No, not me, sorry. I downvoted when it was without any explanation, but I withdrew it after your edit. Probably there is someone who hasn't come back to the page and seen the change. It's a bit of a problem with the way voting works IMO - perhaps there should be a way to know if a post you voted on has been edited.

Comment: It doesn't precisely nullify it though, does it? A downvote is -2 rep and an upvote is +10. So you'd have a net score of +8. Besides, up/downvoting is not some tit-for-tat game. If I'd understood the question well enough to know if your answer was genuinely useful, I'd have upvoted it already. In the end I didn't have the time/inclination to do so, and moved on to other questions - except that I keep getting notified of your comments. I only downvoted because I saw it could never be useful without explanation. And I cannot control the voting habits of others. Sorry, but that's how it is.

Comment: @ADyson But as answer already resolve query of person who had asked question.